# Can I make Windows 10 use two monitors to make one continuous screen if it can't detect the second monitor?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, vga

I'm using a PC running Windows 10 which unfortunately has only one VGA and no HDMI outputs. I recently went down to my nearest generic electronics store and asked them how I could split it across two monitors. They sold me a VGA splitter. Now I've got it setup it's displaying duplicates OK but when I went to setup continuous screen in display settings it can't detect the second monitor. Is there any way I can maybe setup a virtual monitor or something so I can use continuous screen with the second monitor, which is physically there, but it can't detect?

Comment: No, there isn't a way to do what you want from the same video output.

Comment: Return the splitter, Never goto any store for ANYTHING unless you do your research first. They all lie. They all want your monies.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia The Matrox [DualHead2Go](https://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital/) or [TripleHead2Go](https://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/digital/) adapters can do it pretty well. You can probably still get one if you're willing to go second-hand/eBay

Comment: Is it a laptop or desktop?

Comment: @SHawarden No, they can't, they're just overpriced splitters. You should read the comments on Amazon and have a modicum of common sense.

Answer (score 2):

A VGA splitter creates a second connection to a monitor, but only for the purpose of duplicating the original image. This would be useful if your second "monitor" was a projector that required VGA input, but is not useful for your objective.

If your computer has a set of PCI-e slots, you can purchase an additional graphics adapter compatible with Windows 10. You also have an option to use a USB-HDMI adapter if your second monitor has an HDMI input.

If your computer has a currently installed graphics adapter and also has an on-board video output, you can re-enable the on-board video to provide for the objective you seek. This is not as likely in today's systems.

Answer (score -1):

If there is no option for adding internal components to your PC, you will want something along the lines of the now out-of-production Matrox [DualHead2Go](https://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital/) or [TripleHead2Go](https://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/digital/) adapters that will take two roughly identical compatible monitors and connect them to a single port on your computer. The box does the 2-to-1 conversion for you and you get a single, multi-monitor spanning desktop. The box does not take the monitor bezels into account.

It will be a single desktop though, so by default, maximizing a window will cause it to span both monitors. It originally shipped with some software to fix this but I doubt that it's Windows 10 compatible. Fortunately windows 10 has a built in feature where dragging a window to the left or right side of your screen will arrange it side-by-side.

There are some available on [ebay](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=dualhead2go+vga) I'm sure.

If you go this route, make sure you get one that connects to VGA and whatever your monitor's have. There are various input & output combinations of VGA, DVI and DisplayPort out there.

Its also worth noting the specs of your monitor. They will need to support the resolutions and refresh rates available.

Comment: Your product recommendations are a complete rip off. It would be far cheaper for him to buy a PCI-E video card with 2 or 3 ports for 1/10th price.

Comment: That assumes 1) the computer is not a laptop 2) the computer has space for it 3) OP is able to open the computer and dig around inside 4) OP is willing to and 5) OP can find a graphics card that fits whatever form factor is required and costs... 1/10th of 30GBP is... 3GBP or about 6US$

Comment: He said PC. Not laptop. So I don't see it as an assumption. He also says 2 monitors. More of a reason to assume it's a PC. Just saying. Even an ITX case as room for a PCI-E video card with low profile bracket. Your entire answer is literally just a product recommendation, Fred_dot_u and GabrielaGarcia have given the same information that you just repeated.

Comment: Lastly a computer that only has 1 VGA is probably worth next to nothing since it's so old. So dropping $200+ on anything to solve this problem is ridiculous to even suggest.

Comment: Where'd you magic up that 200$?

Comment: From thin air: https://www.amazon.com/Matrox-DualHead2Go-Digital-Edition-D2G-A2D-IF/dp/B000QRTHX8 and https://www.amazon.com/Matrox-TripleHead2Go-Three-Monitor-Graphics-Expansion/dp/B000RMQZ96.

Comment: Regardless of all that, if his question made you assume you should give out a product recommendation, then it should be flagged and closed. Because how ever many product rec you can give, I can give 3 better, cheaper, and more reasonable recommendations, precisely why product recommendations are off topic on SU.

Comment: @Sickest only works if it is a desktop, not a laptop, which we do not know.

Comment: This recommendations do NOT work for the intended OP's purpose. They are just splitters which is what they already have. All it takes is a cursory reading of the comments in Amazon and/or a little common sense: For the OS it's still a **single monitor** connected therefore it can only be mirrored externally by the splitter. **The OS needs to recognize two or more distinct monitors in order to be able to configure an extended  desktop.**

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia They are not splitters. They are de/multiplexers. They present a single monitor to whatever they're connected to. They then display 1/2 (DH2G) or 1/3 (TH2G) the output per connected display, which is exactly what the OP is after. The only caveat being that you can't mix and match physical monitor resolutions & DPIs. I have first hand experience using both the VGA DH2G and the DVI TH2G versions and have nothing but good memories of the pre-Eyefinity-like 2560x1024 and 3840x1024 results. They do exactly what OP wants. Amazon reviews are as expected, all over the place.

Comment: If *they present a single monitor to whatever they're connected to* then they **cannot be configured for an extended desktop** which is what the OP wants. Mirrored displays is what the OP already has. Multiplexing is a gimmick that doesn't allow different windows in different screens as the extended desktop allows. In a nutshell, it's a ridiculous and expensive solution as already commented above.

Comment: OP wants to have the desktop SPLIT across two monitors. What OP got from the signal splitter was a desktop MIRRORED on both monitors. The Matrox GXMs instead convert multiple monitors with matching resolutions into a single virtual monitor. The displayed desktop will be SPLIT across the physical monitors. 2x 1920x1080 monitors would appear as 1x 3840x1080 monitor to the OS. As mentioned in my original answer, maximizing a window will cause it to appear spread across both monitors. If Amazon is the only place OP is willing to look, it will clearly be too expensive. eBay, not so much.

Comment: Short of buying a new GPU or replacing his current one (neither of which we know is possible) there is no other possible solution.